# Pass value to <%- %> variable in HTML

Tags: html, node.js, request, ejs

I have an HTML file in my local system.

```
<div class="<%-var1 %>"></div>  // test.html
```

If I run this code given below :
I am able to replace variable <%-var1 %> in the response.

```
let test = (request, response, next) => {
    return response.render(<path-to-file>, {
        var1: "class1"
    });
}
```

The reponse I get:

```
<div class="class1"></div>
```

but if I move this HTML file to AWS s3 bucket.
(say its on https://mydomain/test.html) and I apply code as given below :

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://mydomain/test.html',
    method: 'GET',
};

let test = (request, response, next) => {
    requestHTTP(options, (err, resp, body) => {
        if (resp || resp.statusCode == 200) {
            return response.render(body,{
                var1: 'class1',
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now I am not able to replace the variable, and getting:

```
<div class="<%-var1 %>"></div>
```

As far as I know, response.render method is no use for my purpose.